# Zing feed plotting multiple series in 1 chart

Tags: javascript, ajax, zingchart

I am trying to plot 2 line series data in ZingChart feed.
Below is my script code.

```
<script>
var chartData = {
    "type":"line",
    "refresh": {
        "type": "feed",
        "transport": "js",
        "url": "feed()",
        "interval": 1000
    },
    "series":[
        {
            "values":[]

        },
        {
            "values":[]
        }
    ]
};



window.onload = function() {
    zingchart.render({
        id: "chartDiv",
        data: chartData,
        height: 600,
        width: "100%"
    });
};

window.feed = function(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        url: "/PerformanceMonitor/showProcessUsage/${processName}",
        success: function (data) {
            var mem = data.mem.size/100000;
            var tick = {
                plot0: parseInt(mem)
                                };
            callback(JSON.stringify(tick));
            var tick2 = {
                    plot1:parseInt(mem/1000)
            };
            callback(JSON.stringify(tick2));
        }
    });
};
```

It gets displayed , but looses the line nature of the graph.Is this the right way ?Is there a better method?. Later I am planning to let user decide how many plots to be allowed in chart at runtime.Is there something in ZingChart that I can make use of ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tick` object contains the data for each series of a plot. That means you can add multiple plots to that object.

You can replace everything in your `success` callback with the following code...

```
var mem = data.mem.size/100000;
var tick = {
    plot0: parseInt(mem),
    plot1: parseInt(mem/1000)
};
callback(JSON.stringify(tick));
```

If you wanted to add a third plot to the series, you'd just add a `plot2` attribute (since ZingChart's series have a 0-based index).

I'm on the ZingChart team. Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Thank you :) It works fine. I now want to let the user decide on the fly to add/ delete a plot series. Can you point me where I should be looking for this ? and how it can be achieved ?

Comment: Since we just added another plot to the `tick` object with `plot1`, you can add more that same way with `plot2`, `plot3`, etc. You can see a demo of that at http://www.zingchart.com/features/real-time-data-charts/

Comment: Could you please take a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612512/static-chart-with-timestamp-on-x-axis